# Complex conjugate in Mathematica

Tags: complex

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two complex variables, how to realize：
$$\text{Conjugate}[a+b]=\text{Conjugate}[a]+\text{Conjugate}[b] $$
in Mathematica.

Suppose in following situation, I want to simplify:

```
Refine[Conjugate[(I a + c)^2 + b], {Element[{a, c}, Reals]}]
(* (-I a + c)^2+Conjugate[b] *)
```

where a is a complex variable, b is a general complex variable.

I tried:

```
Refine[Conjugate[(I a + c)^2], {Element[{a, c}, Reals]}]
(*(-I a + c)^2*)
```

but

```
Refine[Conjugate[(I a + c)^2 + b], {Element[{a, c}, Reals]}]
(* Conjugate[b + (I a + c)^2] *)
```

Comment: What is the context in which you need this? Are you simplifying an expression? Can you give an example of the expression that you want to transform, in Mathematica code?

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, I will re-edit my post!

Comment: This seems related to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/271674/86543)

Comment: @userrandrand Thanks! That's helpful!